# Everything moves around when making iPhone app Universal Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.3

As of now my iPhone works on iPad as it should except my problem is that some images partially show as if they got zoomed in on. So I tried turning universal devices on but that's just as bad since everything shifts into different locations.

I am using Auto Layout and this is an old app I'm wanting to update.

Comment: Quick edit: Just realized the image issue seems to do with different device screen sizes.

Comment: Are the images the only problem? The content mode might be wrong (I suspect `ScaleToFill` or `AspectFill`).

Comment: the image changing in different screen sizes is my main concern, I just tried those two and no luck

Comment: Yes, I meant these two are likely wrong ;) Try `AspectFit`?

Comment: didn't work either :(

Comment: Since it doesn't seem to be a trivial issue, we cannot help you without more information. Post screenshots of the issue. Add which constraints are on your views. Are there any breaking constraints? Are all views managed with AutoLayout?

Comment: is there no way to make an app auto resize depending on the screen size for all devices?

Comment: Of course there is - using AutoLayout and size classes correctly. Please update your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing constraints was the cause of the problem!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like that missing constraints is the cause of the problem! You might want to redo the layout and constraints.